# Installation of latest nodejs 0.10.29 on windows server 2003

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded the latest installables of node.js from http://nodejs.org/download/ 
I want to install the Node on Windows Server 2003, but it alerts me that the 'installation package does not supported by this processor type".
Could anyone help me, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the download page there are 32-bit and 64-bit installation packages. You can't install the 64-bit package on a processor which only supports 32-bit. Find out your processor type and install the correct package. I assume it's an old computer, so most likely you will need the 32-bit package.

Comment: I think you are right. I will install 32-bit installation package